# How to put JavaScript from tutorial into my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cakephp

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to get a slideshow working in my website. I'm following this tutorial: http://www.queness.com/post/1450/jquery-photo-slide-show-with-slick-caption-tutorial-revisited

Unfortunately it doesn't go into a beginners level of detail as to how to get it installed. I know what I should do with the HTML and the CSS but I'm not sure where I should be putting the JavaScript. Does it go in a separate file or something?  How do I get it to work?

Also I'm trying to do this within cakephp so if there's any specific cakey thing I can do that'd be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy all that JavaScript on your [referenced page](http://www.queness.com/post/1450/jquery-photo-slide-show-with-slick-caption-tutorial-revisited). Save to a new file `slide.js` or something like that.

Edit your HTML document to include a reference to the jQuery libraby, and that new JavaScript file you've just created:

```
 <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/slide.js" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put JavaScript in an external file with a `.js` extension, and include that in an HTML page using the `script` tag:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="yourscript.js"></script>`

Alternatively, you can write the script directly in the `script` element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Your script here
</script>
```

Also note that as the tutorial you are following uses jQuery, you will need to download and include the jQuery library in your page.

The `script` tags can be placed anywhere in the document, but are usually found inside the `head` tag, or just before the closing `body` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on SO Helen.

That script uses the jQuery library so you have to also include that. http://jquery.com/

JavaScript can best be placed in seperate file with the extension .js

Add the javascript files just before the `</body>` tag on your page like:

```
<script src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery/jquery-slideshow2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```